# Learning new words via etymology

Tags: meaning, etymology, meaning-in-context, vocabulary, etymological-fallacy

if I learned the “true meaning” of a word via etymology, would it help to get all its possible meaning in any context?

Comment: What do you mean by "true meaning" of a word? Are you asking whether knowing the "true meaning" (whatever that is) helps or whether knowing the etymology helps? Either way I'm sure the answer is no, it won't provide all possible meanings in every context.

Comment: There is a well- (but insufficiently-) known principle called the 'etymological fallacy'. Essentially, this occurs whenever anyone says "That was what XXXX meant when it appeared in the English lexicon (or even worse, what the Latin original meant), so that's the proper meaning now." (1) It (XXXX) _may_ retain this meaning, and have this meaning alone. (2) It may have acquired new senses, equally or more idiomatic ('true')  nowadays. (3) The oldest sense may nowadays even be obsolete. (4) The word may be totally obsolete. // Etymologies are very useful, interesting, often complex – and tricky.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "perhaps".

The etymology of a word gives you its source/root **and** its development to its current meaning. **If you learn the etymology, you will learn the current meaning also.**

OED:

> **etymology: The facts relating to the origin of a particular word or the historical development of its form and meaning; the origin of a particular word.**
>
> 2010   A. Potter Authenticity Hoax i. 49   *The very idea of what it means to be sick (and lurking in the etymology of the word dis-ease) is that something is not right.*

However, I am not sure how knowing that "Avocado" has its origins in the  Nahuatl (Aztec) word **āhuacatl**, which means “testicle”, will help, although it does give an idea of the shape.

That said, any study of language is likely to give you a better understanding languages as a whole.

Comment: TBH, I am not interested to know every historical origin of a word as much as I want to know what it is the current general meaning of the word.

Comment: What is the difference between the "historical origin of a word" and its etymology?

Comment: No different...